# What is the purpose of the chamfer at the ends of this piece of clapboard?

Tags: joinery

I need to replace a few of those clapboards.

[image]

In order for them to stack, I need to remove half of the material on the intersecting volume.

What is the purpose of the chamfer and the surface #2 ?
[image: The original board in blue, the bare wood board is a work in progress to make the replacement part]

[image]

[image]

The clapboards are symmetric about the three origin plane.

There is no play in the joint, i.e the width of the joint is exactly equal to the thickness of the board on surface #2.

Those joints bear no load, as the vast majority of the contact area is on the rest of the board.

Answer (score 2):

Without a bit more detail, it's hard to be sure, but I would say the makers of that joint cut the mating slot into which the crossing board slides narrower than the thickness of the clapboards.   The removal of material at surface 2 is to reduce the thickness of the clapboard in the joint to the width of the mating slot.   The reason someone would do this is that the cut edges of the mating slots are thus recessed in the joint and covered by the crossing clapboard.   I would expect there to be a "surface 2" recessed on both sides of the joint, so both edges are covered.   The "tenon" left between the surfaces has to be the same width as as the slots.

If you do this, then the chamfer you label 1 is actually a miter, and is necessary to remove interference in the interior corner of the joint.

(Edited to add) Actually, what I said above isn't completely correct.   If there the "surface 2" cut you reference is done on both sides of the slot, then all four corners of the slot would require the chamfer/miter.  My pictures don't show this correctly, and are hiding an impossible overlap of wood in three of the corners.  However, if only the inside face of the clapboard have the surface recessed, then only the inside to the face, inside to the length of the clapboard, corner needs to be mitered.   Looking more closely at your pictures, I think that's most likely what is going on.   The joint then assembles as in the third picture, just attached.

[image: Outside view]

[image: Inside view]

[image: Correct Joint]

Comment: Hopefully the OP will clarify, but his drawing does clearly show chamfers on all four of the arrises adjacent to the recessed surface of the joint.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes chamfers at joints are not for practical purpose but only for appearance, providing 'shadow line'.

Sometimes chamfers are added to make joints easier to put together, as on inside edges of dovetails, leading edge of tenon or dowel. I think this is purpose here, **to make joints easier to assemble**.